# How to set control (windows control) position to some other control relative postion

Tags: c#, vb.net, controls, window

I want to set control position relative to other control so when i make one control hide then other control move up like this.

Ex.
Label1
Label2
Label3

When i hide Label2 so output will be

Label1
Label3

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FlowLayoutPanel`

Though, you might need to set the `FlowDirection` to `TopDown`

Just put those labels into the panel